# Definition of determinant based on permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant

So I am just about to be finished with my first semester of Linear Algebra. They go over things extremely quickly without much explanation. During the semester there is course work to be finished, or otherwise one will automatically fail the course. So all students are doing whatever they can to finish the course work.

Now that the semester is over with the exam in two months, I want to spend all my time on understanding what I just learned. Since the script from the uni is absolutely atrocious, I am working with Hofmann&Kunze's Linear Algebra.

So on page 150 of this book, we have:

Suppose $D$ is an alternating n-linear function on $n\times n$ matrices over K. Let A be an  $n\times n$ matrix over K with rows $a_1,a_2,....,a_n$.  If we denote the rows of the $n\times n$ identity matrix over K by $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,.....,\epsilon_n$, then
$$a_i=\sum_{j=1}^nA(i,j)\epsilon_j, 1\le i\le n$$

Hence$$D(A)=D(\sum_jA(1,j)\epsilon_j,a_2,....,a_n)=\sum_jA(1,j)D(\epsilon_1,a_2,...a_n)$$

And the author goes on to do this until,

$$D(A)=\sum_{k_1,k_2,....,k_n}A(1,k_1)A(2,k_2)...A(n,k_n)D(\epsilon_{k1},\epsilon_{k2},....,\epsilon_{kn})$$

I just dont understand the point of doing this. What's the intention behind all this? Maybe I did not understand the equations correctly and would be very glad if someone could point it out.

Comment: One motivation: Consider the $n$ rows as a set $B$ of members of $K^n.$ The row-reduction process (for finding out whether $B$ is a linearly independent set) produces a sequence of matrices, all with the same determinant. The process ends with at least one row being all $0$'s iff $B$ is linearly dependent iff the determinant is $0$. Hence, regarding the matrix $A$ as representing a linear function  on $K^n$, the image $A[K^n]$ is all of $K^n$ iff det$(A)\ne 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the last equation. This is a sum of $n^n$ elements. Each of these elements is a product of $n$ elements of original matrix and determinant of a matrix composed of a rows all zeros and one 1, looking like $(0, 0, 1, ..., 0)$.

I guess the next step will be to prove that if there are two identical rows in some matrix, than it's determinant is 0. So, among these $n^n$ elements not zero are only the those elements having all different $k_i$. That is not zero are only those elements where $(k_1, k_2, ... k_n)$ is a permutation of $(1, 2, ..., n)$. There are $n!$ of them.

Next step will be to prove that determinant of the matrix is 1 or -1 depending on parity of the permutation.

And thus we get that determinant is a sum of $n!$ elements:
$$D(A)=\sum_{all \; k_i \; permutaions}A(1,k_1)A(2,k_2)...A(n,k_n) parity(permutation)$$

Hope that helps..